# Doctrine Join - Error: Class 'alias' is not defined

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entitymanager, query-builder, doctrine-query

I'm making a query using the `QueryBuilder` object from Doctrine. In that query I have a `join` which I don't know why, gives me an error saying that the alias (`fe`) for one of the tables (`F_Expenses`) is not defined. In SQL, my query would looks like this:

```
select * from f_expenses
join users_f_expenses on f_expenses.id=users_f_expenses.id_form
where login="Jack1234";
```

This being said, this is the function which contains my `QueryBuilder` object:

```
public function getFormsAction($login){

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
             ->select('fe')
             ->from('intranetBundle:Entity\F_Expenses', 'fe')
             ->innerJoin('fe', 'intranetBundle:Entity\Users_F_Expenses', 'ufe', 'fe.id = ufe.idForm')
             ->where('ufe.login = :login')
             ->setParameter('login', $login)
             ->getQuery();


    $formsOfTheUser = $qb->getArrayResult();

    $serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
    $serializer->serialize($formsOfTheUser, 'json');

    return $formsOfTheUser;
}
```

Note that yes, the field called `id_form` in the database, is named as `idForm` in the Entity. This is exactly the error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 62 near 'fe intranetBundle:Entity\Users_F_Expenses': Error: Class 'fe' is not defined.

I've just followed the [API](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#join-clauses), first argument of the `join` is used to specify the alias of the `FROM`, so `fe`. Second and third parameters are, respectively, the join-table and its alias (so `intranetBundle:Entity\Users_F_Expenses` and `ufe`), and finally the fourth is the `on` clause (`fe.id = ufe.idForm`).

I've tried to delete the `join` line and make a normal `select` from the first table and it worked, so I'm pretty sure that the error has something to do with the `join` clause.

Comment: I don't think query builder can do joins unless you explicitly add joins in your entities/schema files. You can still do joins of course but you will have to do them in native SQL or possibly use DQL. But you might want to consider adding you relations to your entity files. See: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html